# Having Single Case Else in Nested Select VB

Tags: vbscript

My code is like below

```
Dim Msg As String

Select Item_name

Case "Fruit"

  Select Fruit_Name
      Case "Apple"
          //Do something
      Case "Orange"
          //Do something
      Case Else
          Msg="Erorr"
  End Select

Case "Vegitable"

        //Do something
Case Else
    Msg="Error"

End Select
```

Can I have single Case Else for both select? As both case Else are same. If so how can I implement?

Comment: to test 2 vars you need 2 select

Comment: Is this VBA/VBScript or VB.Net?

Comment: The Else cases are much too simple to consider fixing this.  If they are not then don't hesitate to use a Boolean variable.

Comment: "Dim Msg As String" (typed Dim) is NOT VBScript.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

**VBScript**: You can use a comma separated list of items after the `Case` to compare them to the value specified after the `Select Case`:

```
>> For Each Plant In Split("Apple Orange Cabbage Salad")
>>     Select Case Plant
>>        Case "Apple", "Cabbage"
>>          WScript.Echo "cook",  Plant
>>        Case "Orange"
>>          WScript.Echo "throw away", Plant
>>        Case Else
>>          WScript.Echo "feed to rabbit", Plant
>>     End Select
>> Next
>>
cook Apple
throw away Orange
cook Cabbage
feed to rabbit Salad
```

**Update wrt comment:**

You can compare boolean expressions (`Case`) to True/False (`Select Case`):

```
>> For Each Kind In Split("fruit vegetable")
>>     For Each Spec In Split("apple cabbage")
>>         Select Case True
>>            Case Kind = "fruit" And Spec = "apple"
>>              WScript.Echo Kind, Spec
>>            Case Kind = "vegetable" And Spec = "apple"
>>              WScript.Echo "surprise", Kind, Spec
>>         End Select
>>     Next
>> Next
>>
fruit apple
surprise vegetable apple
```

A detailed description of a **real world problem** would be needed to discuss whether a nested `If` statement would be a better strategy.

**Update wrt comment II:**

Use a [decision table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table) to analyse the conditions and the implied actions. Then plan and implement your "evaluate the conditions" tree, use `If` and/or `Select Case` as appropriate to present the conditions and their (inter)dependencies clearly. If some (combinations of) conditions need the 'same' action, put those into a Sub/Function.

(see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614%28v=vs.84%29.aspx))

Comment: I think he have 2 conditions: `Item_name` = `Fruit` and `Fruit_name` = `Apple` to `do something`, it can't simply to put in one `select case`

Comment: I just given two conditions here just for example, totally I have  5 conditions which all have nested Select and for each condition case else would be same.